# what happens when boolean mask of numpy array is just a single value

Tags: python, numpy

I know that boolean array can be used as a mask in a numpy array.
But when I use a single value as a mask in a numpy array, strange thing happened:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5] 
result = np.array(x)[True]
print(result)
```

It turns out to be [[1 2 3 4 5]]. Why there is a double bracket? What does Python do in this case?

Comment: check the shape, (1,5).  I saw this asked not too long ago, but can't search for the duplicate now,  I think `np.array(x)[False]` is (0,5) shape

Comment: @hpaulj indeed it's `array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=int64)`, so would be anything with more than one value `np.array(x)[True, False]`

Comment: what does shape=(0,5) mean ?

Comment: It means your array has 0 rows and 5 columns, it has no elements but the shape is `(0, 5)`

Comment: So this is a wierd situation in Python. We should try to avoid that, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to broadcasting, as your input array doesn't have the correct shape.

To perform real boolean indexing, you would need to pass a **list**:

```
np.array(x)[[True, False, True, False, True]]
# array([1, 3, 5])
```

Obviously with `[[True]]` this wouldn't work as the shape is mismatching:

```
np.array(x)[[True]]
# IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0;
# dimension is 5 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

When you run `np.array(x)[True]` this is more or less equivalent to:

```
np.array(x).reshape((1, -1))[[True]]
# array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```